# 3d vector algebra question

Tags: geometry, 3d

All the x,y,z of the black dots are known variables.

I have a line, as shown in the diagram, that has a $16.5^\circ$ angle relative to the $XY$ plane.

How can I get the yellow $(x,y,z)$ as shown?

[image: 3d image]

Comment: Hi welcome to MSE, you shouldn't put links in your question to explain your problem. Try to explain it clearly and help will come. Also make sure to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve your question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P= (x,y,z)$ is on the line that connects $P_1 = (121,53, 0) $ with $P_2 = (118, 41,6) $.  We want to locate the point $P$ such that the angle between $\vec{P_3 P} $ and the $z$-axis is $90^\circ - 16.5^\circ = 73.5^\circ$, where $P_3 = (109, 41, 0) $.  Now point $P$ is given by

$ P = (1 - t) P_1 + t P_2 = (1 - t) (121,53, 0) + t (118, 41, 6) = (121,53, 0) + t (-3, -12, 6 ) $

Hence, the equation we want to solve is

$ \cos 73.5^\circ = \dfrac{ \mathbf{k} \cdot (P - P_3) } { \| P - P_3 \| } $

Now, $P - P_3 = (121,53,0) + t (-3, -12, 6) - (109, 41, 0) = (12, 12, 0) + t (-3, -12, 6) $

So the above equation reduces to

$ \cos 73.5^\circ = \dfrac{ 6 t }{\sqrt{ (12 - 3 t)^2 + (12 - 12 t)^2 + (6 t)^2 }} $

From which,

$\cos^2 73.5^\circ ( 288 - 360 t + 189 t^2 ) = 36 t^2 $

Solving, we get

$ t = 0.568783919 $

The other value of $t$ is extraneous.

With this, point $P$ is found by substituting the found $t$ into the above expression for $P$, and this gives us

$P = (121 - 3 t, 53- 12 t, 6 t) = (119.2936, 46.17459, 3.412704) $

Comment: P = 119.1898,45.75935,3.620324, if you calculate the angle of the line starting from P to the P3. the angle is ≈ 17.266066811799565 degrees, which does not match the 16.5 angle that was given. Why is it?

Comment: There was an error in the expression involving the components of the vector $P - P_3$.  I've corrected that error.   And now the result I got matches the result of the other answer.

Comment: Thanks! I have learnt so much from this answer!!!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Calling

$$
\cases{
p=(x,y,z)\\
p_1= (121,53,0)\\
p_2=(118,41,0)\\
p_3=(109,41,0)
}
$$

we have

$$
\cases{
\frac{6}{z}-\frac{53-41}{53-y}=0\\
\frac{6}{z}-\frac{121-118}{121-x}=0\\
\frac{z}{\|p-p_3\|}-\sin(16.5^{\circ})=0
}
$$

solving for $(x,y,z)$ we got

$$
p = (119.294,46.175,3.413)
$$

[image]